# Is it possible to charge a MacBook Air M1 with another MacBook Air M1?

Tags: macbook-pro

What do two such computers do if they are cabled together by a USB-C? Does the one with higher charge charge the one with a lower one?

Is there any application one can download to manage a situation like this?

Comment: If you have two Macs, try it and let us know your findings!

Comment: I actually read this is supposed work out on factory settings. I’m positively surprised.